# Publish Procedure Failed - Simulink code generation with TwinCAT Target file

Tags: simulink, twincat

I would like to develop an application in Matlab/Simulink which will be integrated in TwinCAT by TcCOM modules (code generation with TwinCAT.tlc target file).

I have some problems in the PUBLISH PROCEDURE!!!

First of all, I have to mention that I passed through all the steps mentioned in the TwiCAT – Simulink Handbook (see on page 9: https://download.beckhoff.com/download/document/automation/twincat3/TwinCAT_3_Matlab_Simulink_EN.pdf ). The next steps are accomplished:

- Matlab R2015b is installed;
- TwinCAT 3 is installed and embedded in Visual Studio 2013;
- Microsoft Windows Driver Kit is installed (WinDDK 7600.16385.1)
- Twincat 3 Target for Matlab/Simulink (TE1400) is installed and embedded in Matlab;
- The necessary licenses are activated;
  The application is very basic, it has an INPUT and an OUTPUT block, a SUM and a CONSTANT block. 
  The Simulink model have been configured as:
- Solver: Fixed Step solver (ode3) with 0.005 fixed-step size;
- Code Generation: TwinCAT.tlc System target file;
- Code Generation -> Tc Build: Publish Module CHECKED

When I try to Build Model, Simulink returns the next error message:

‘Publish Procedure Failed – MGFcn:43’

and

'error MSB3231: Unable to remove directory'

If you need, I can attach the .txt file with the errors.

If I leave the Publish Module UNCHECKED, Simulink generates C++ code without errors. But, I need to have TcCOM modules.

I hope that I delivered all the necessary information.

Comment: just a short guess. Did you try running the programs as administrator?

Comment: That was the first step! :)